# How to customize Joomla registration form?

Tags: plugin, user, registration, com-users

1. How to create proper override folder for com_user? Apparently, simply copying it to template/html folder doesn't work
2. What is displayed on registration page is largely controlled by the .xml file, can it also be overridden?
3. My goal is to remove the required "Name" field. Someone has taught me an alternative to remove this field in user plugin. I did this, however, although the "Name" field doesn't show on registration page, it is still at work and prevent user from submit the form because they haven't filled this required field.

Comment: Can you share your code? Without seeing it, it's impossible to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin: https://github.com/vlasenkofedor/usergroup
See README.md: in Main options the second "Remove the Name field. The name field will not be displayed. Will be replaced by the name from the mail"